# WiFi modem with outgoing traffic firewall

Tags: wireless-networking, firewall, modem

So here is the problem- I have a compromised macbook, seems that reinstalling the whole system doesn’t work, as what’s there inside is deeper then OS level. I need a device, that acts as a wifi modem (with a sim card), and where I can setup a white list of hosts where all wifi network can access. Or some similar portable setup.

Comment: Precisely which MacBook? Exactly what have you done to 'reinstall' it? There's really very little 'deeper than OS level' that could carry an infection.

Comment: Mbp 2015, Made Bootable drive (on the same machine), then reformatted hard drive, then reinstall from this drive. Rootkits are capable of keeping themselves on efi drive.

Comment: You made the bootable drive on the infected Mac. Instead use Internet Recovery, then nuke & pave. In Disk Utility, use the device view [cmd/2] rather than the volume view & erase the entire drive, not just the volume.